# After stopping JVM, unable to start it again

Tags: python, flask, jvm, weka

I am using [python-weka-wrapper](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper) which then uses [javabridge](https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/) library for running and accessing the Java Virtual Machine to utilize whatever [WEKA](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has to offer.
So my application has a frontend in ReactJS, and backend server in flask. For each request to a particular endpoint, a new thread is created by [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module of python. It is on this thread, JVM (using weka.core.jvm ) is started, the script is executed, and then stopped. After a second request to the same endpoint, a new JVM is unable to start.
Error: `RuntimeError: Failed to start Java VM.`
Help me with the implementation details for such an app. Is it possible to run JVM as a daemon in the backend, something like that, and stopping the JVM only when the server is stopped?

Answer (score 3):

pww relies on the [javabridge](https://pypi.org/project/javabridge/) library with which it is not possible to restart the JVM after stopping it. Also, pww has not been implemented with multi-threading in mind and Weka by itself isn't thread-safe by default.

Comment: There could be a workaround, according to this github issue comment: https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/88#issuecomment-817875968