# I am using Python weka wrapper. i unfortunately used jvm.stop(). now my jvm wont start again

Tags: python, java, weka

I am using Python Weka wrapper. I unfortunately used jvm.stop(). Now my JVM won't start again. How do I go about solving this? Is there anyway I can get the JVM running again?

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
import javabridge
jvm.start()
```

Comment: Is there any method like `jvm.start();`

Comment: import weka.core.jvm as jvm
import javabridge  jvm.start()

Comment: basically my code. I am importing the weka.core.jvm library. I am also importing javabridge. then i do jvm.start(). that is throwing me an error saying it failed to start Java VM

Comment: Which IDE are you using

Comment: jupyter notebook

Comment: In your project directory, has it created any folder like py_cache ?

Comment: how do i locate that? atleast in my folder i cant see anyting like that...

Comment: Okay I think I found a solution.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51795945/17022570

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After stopping JVM, unable to start it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795945/after-stopping-jvm-unable-to-start-it-again)

Comment: sadly they say it cannot be started again.

Comment: Who say it cannot be started?

Comment: "pww relies on the javabridge library with which it is not possible to restart the JVM after stopping it. Also, pww has not been implemented with multi-threading in mind and Weka by itself isn't thread-safe by default." this is the answer in the link

Comment: Okay Then try `pip uninstall weka` and then install it again `pip install weka`

Comment: still not working

Comment: After calling jvm.stop() you need to restart your kernel. Unfortunately. A limitation of the javabridge library.